# jre\lib\security\cacerts is not a legal command

Tags: java, command-line, certificate, java-6

I am trying to run a command to install the certificate. Below is the command

"C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\keytool -importcert -file name.cer-keystore "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts-storepass changeit -alias XXXX

and I am getting below error. Please let me kow what is wrong here.

error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts is not a legal command

Thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoting and spacing is off:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\keytool" -importcert -file name.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -alias capitalone
```

Comment: Thanks Man..!! I had same command first time but some how that was also breaking. This time it worked though. May be I was doing something wrong.